# Multiply 2 columns from 2 seperate tables and add the result into a seperate column

Tags: sql

I am new to this and its frying my brain.

I have 2 tables a product table name,unit price and and order table which has quantity and total price.
I have this so far but am unable to figure out how to get the result into an existing table.

```
SELECT a.product_name, (a.product_unit_price * b.order_quantity)
FROM t_product a, t_order_details b,
Where a.product_name = b.t_product_product_name;
);
```

What can I do to get the multiplication result added to the order total price column in the order details table?

Comment: Syntax details depend on your actual RDBMS. Always declare it.

Comment: Hi sorry mega busy.  Yes you helped me massively thanks.  I ended up with this trigger to get the job done.Trigger order total
create or replace TRIGGER ORDER_TOTAL 
AFTER INSERT ON t_order_details 
BEGIN
UPDATE t_order_details b
SET    order_total =  (SELECT a.product_unit_price * b.order_quantity
FROM   t_product a
WHERE  a.product_name = b.t_product_product_name);
END;

Comment: RDBMS stands for "Relational Database Management System". Your database system would make this question much more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Errors are the comma before `Where` and the dangling `) ;`.

But use a clearer explicit `JOIN` for the `SELECT` instead:

```sql
SELECT a.product_name, (a.product_unit_price * b.order_quantity)
FROM   t_product a
JOIN   t_order_details b ON a.product_name = b.t_product_product_name;
```

> What can I do to get the multiplication result added to the order total price column in the order details table?

You probably mean to `UPDATE`? (Postgres syntax):

```sql
UPDATE t_order_details AS b
SET    total_price =  a.product_unit_price * b.order_quantity
FROM   t_product AS a
WHERE  a.product_name = b.t_product_product_name;
```

Or the same with a correlated subquery (should work in most RDBMS):

```sql
UPDATE t_order_details AS b
SET    total_price =  (SELECT a.product_unit_price * b.order_quantity
                       FROM   t_product AS a
                       WHERE  a.product_name = b.t_product_product_name);
```